# DBI SQL_VARCHAR is not supporting, getting error DBD::ODBC::st bind_param failed: Data type is not supported. [typeId=-9] (SQL-HYC00)

Tags: perl, gridgain, dbd

I am using Gridgain as database. Perl script is written to read data from xml and insert/update the data to Gridgain database.

Passing XML data as hash to following line of code

```
use DBI;
use DBD::ODBC;
use DBI qw(:sql_types);
use POSIX;

{$sthHandl}->bind_param($Bindpos,$BindHashRef->{$Bindpos}->{'BINDVAL'},{TYPE => $BindHashRef->{$Bindpos}->{'BINDPOSTYPE'}}) or $ST = 1;
```

Here: `$BindHashRef->{$Bindpos}->{'BINDPOSTYPE'}` is the string `SQL_VARCHAR`.

Script throwing following error when executed:

> DBD::ODBC::st bind_param failed: Data type is not supported. [typeId=-9] (SQL-HYC00)

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: What's the output of `say $BindHashRef->{$Bindpos}->{'BINDPOSTYPE'};`?

Comment: @ikegami                                                                                                                 
`print ("$BindHashRef->{$Bindpos}->{'BINDPOSTYPE'} \n");`                                              
SQL_VARCHAR 
`print ("$BindHashRef->{$Bindpos}->{'BINDVAL'} \n");`                                                            
ADDONPREMDISP

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)", "[mre]" and their linked pages. We need the smallest code necessary to duplicate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You say you are passing the string `SQL_VARCHAR`, but the correct value is the number twelve.

```
$ perl -Mv5.10 -e'use DBI qw( :sql_types ); say SQL_VARCHAR;'
12
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved after modifying code as below:

```
if ($BindHashRef->{$Bindpos}->{'BINDPOSTYPE'} eq "SQL_VARCHAR")
        {
{$sthHandl}->bind_param($Bindpos,$BindHashRef->{$Bindpos}->{'BINDVAL'},{TYPE => DBI::SQL_VARCHAR}) or $ST = 1;
        }
else
        {
           {$sthHandl}->bind_param($Bindpos,$BindHashRef->{$Bindpos}->{'BINDVAL'},{TYPE => $BindHashRef->{$Bindpos}->{'BINDPOSTYPE'}}) or $ST = 1;
        }
```